# How to add/update items to existing combobox periodically?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to modify (add or remove) items of a combobox while the form is already running, I tried the methode add `this.comboBox1.Items.add("test2");` but it only add the item if it runs before `Application.Run(form);` .

Why it is not updating/adding the item in the combobox ?

**Form1.designer.cs:**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "test"});
            this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(422, 116);
            this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 24);
            this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        public void test() {
            this.comboBox1.Items.add("test2");
        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 form = new Form1();

            Application.Run(form);
            form.test();

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

How to achieve a periodical update of items by a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a very helpful feature which is [timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/run-procedures-at-set-intervals-with-wf-timer-component).

I have used a timer initialized inside the form constructor in order to update periodically the combobox, in the following example it added an item which is current time to the dropbox every 2 seconds for 5 times:

**Form1.Designer.cs:**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "test"});
            this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(422, 116);
            this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 24);
            this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";

            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;

    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeTimer();
        }


        private void InitializeTimer()
        {
            counter = 0;

            timer1.Interval = 2000;
            timer1.Enabled = true;

            this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (counter >= 5)
            {
                // Exit loop code.  
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                counter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // Run your procedure here.  
                // Increment counter.  
                counter = counter + 1;
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SelectIndexChanged, you should use the click event

In this example I use a button to add an combobox item eveytime I click on it

might not be the best approach but it works fine

```
 List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
        int i=0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            itemList.Add("Test N° "+i);
        }

        private void comboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            foreach(string item in itemList)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }

        }
```

### [image]

And your programm isn't well made, Form1.cs.designer is use to create the UI (User Interface) of your programm, you MUST NOT add your function here.

FormX.cs.designer = UI, design

FormX.cs = functions

Programm.cs = defined which FormX.cs will run first (new(Form1))

Comment: I am not looking to control the adding items manually but a function will do

Comment: I show how to add it manually but a function can add it if you want

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it to add item with a function

Example :

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddTenItems();
        }
        List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
        int i=0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            itemList.Add("Test N° "+i);
            i++;
        }
        private void AddTenItems()
        {
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                itemList.Add("Added N°" + i);
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            foreach(string item in itemList)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }

        }
```

[image]

Comment: I am new to C# so i appreciate your explanations, as in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774624/how-to-add-items-to-existing-combobox-after-the-form-is-already-running#comment107527221_60774816) how if i want the function to update periodically and not at the construction or loading event?

Comment: I guess it's impossible to load dynamically combobox items without re-opening them :-/